# WinForm application behaves differently in different system

Tags: c#, winforms

I have winform application with many controls but the main control is tree on form. The application is working fine in my system but when this was tested in another system this behaves differntly. Tree size got changed and overlapped other controls and hence some of the controls are not visible. This is surprising for me. What could be the issue? I verified DPI setting and msinfo32 but could not see any differnce in both the systems.

Comment: Can you give more info about it? What size are you using for your form? Are you using a custom font? Those can cause problems.

Comment: Install .net framework 4.7.  this will correct the behavior.  Re-target to that version recompile.

Comment: If there is a problem with .NET version then I could see the issue in both the systems and not in one system.I am using VS 2013 and all my projects are built with .NET Framework 4. Both the systems have same configuration. Tree control is 3rd party control.

Comment: Form font is Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt and size is 535, 648.

Comment: Any comment from anyone?

Comment: `...when this was tested in another system this behaves differntly` you need to provide detailed descriptions of both systems. What's different about the second? Also, you need to add more info on the problem itself: which controls malfunction? how? Ideally, you need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I solved this issue. This was problem with DPI. The application was developed with DPI 125% and hence controls are overlapping wherever DPI was 100%. Any app must be developed with 100% DPI to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with DPI only. Application was developed with 125% DPI and that's why controls were overlapping in other system where default DPI was 100%.